# GitHub makes my green squares less green the more I commit. Why?

Tags: github

Everyone knows that the more you commit to github in a single day, the darker green your square is on your profile.

But the more you commit it seems that GitHub retroactively goes back and lightens your dark green squares.

Does anyone know the formula for how GitHub does this?

Bonus question: One of the most active people on GitHub had over 2000 commits on a single day. Any guesses on what was going on that day? Scripting? Hacking? Single letter commits?

Comment: People with huge single day commits usually run a script/bot/crawler that periodically updates the repo with new committed information (eg every 5 min). It is not exactly recommended but I have seen it done before.

Their intention is harmless and tend to not realise that it gives them huge commit statistics.

Comment: You said: "But the more you commit it seems that GitHub retroactively goes back and lightens your dark green squares -- Does anyone know the formula for how GitHub does this".  I would guess that the darkness value is not absolute but relative.  Think about it -- if last week your most active day of check-ins ever was 10 checkins, it should be darkest green -- but now today you accomplish 25 checkins, then relatively speaking, the day with 10 checkins should no longer be darkest green. (IOW it does not need to be literally 'retroactive' -- just a rolling average)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's several [examples](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats/blob/c941e03f6b1acaba4ef302d565d292cfa817fedb/lib/index.js#L229) of people implementing their own activity graph, one would assume GitHub itself uses a similar algorithm.

In terms of the commit volumes: remember that committing to GitHub, like most things, can be scripted - for either nefarious, or [awesome](https://github.com/gelstudios/gitfiti) purposes.